# Mikrotik CHR with public ip behind a proxmox Eoip not work

Tags: proxmox, mikrotik

i have this problem:

I have a ionos dedicated server i have installed a proxmox on it, i have an additional ip address for my routeros virtualized machine ionos delivered me this ip via vlan 1010:

enp35s0-vid1010->Vmbr0<--CHR RouterOS ether1 217.xxx.xxx.164/32 gateway 10.255.255.1

Untagged is the server ip
217.xx.xx.10/32 gateway 10.255.255.1
Server is able to go in internet and receive connection on his public address.
Chr is able to go in internet and receive connection on his public address.

Eoip tunnel not work on virtualized CHR

CHR can ping the remote routeros ip.

Remote router can ping CHR.

No firewall rule on each side.

Gre protocol seems to work:
if i create a pptp server on CHR i am able to connect via pptp client from remote side, everything work except eoip :(

Comment: enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com